SwiftUI @Published Property Not Updating View When Using Class vs Struct
I have a minimal reproducible example in SwiftUI that demonstrates an issue with view updates when using a class vs a struct. The view updates correctly when using a struct, but it doesn't update when using a class. Below is the code:
SimpleView.swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct SimpleView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = SampleViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.timeCounter.showerTimeMinutes)
            Button("Update Minutes Class") {
                viewModel.timeCounter.showerTimeMinutes = "15"
            }
            
            VStack {
                Text(viewModel.timeCounterStruct.showerTimeMinutes)
                Button("Update Minutes Struct") {
                    viewModel.timeCounterStruct.showerTimeMinutes = "15"
                }
            }
            
            
            VStack {
                Text(viewModel.timerCounterPublisher.showerTimeMinutes)
                Button("Update Minutes Class with Publisher") {
                    viewModel.timerCounterPublisher.showerTimeMinutes = "15"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SimpleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SimpleView()
    }
}

SampleViewModel.swift
class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timeCounter = SampleTimeCounter()
    @Published var timeCounterStruct = SampleTimeCounterStruct()
    @Published var timerCounterPublisher = SampleTimeCounterPublihser()
}

// This is support class that will save the shower time for next time.
class SampleTimeCounter {
    var showerTimeMinutes =  "00"
}

class SampleTimeCounterPublihser: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showerTimeMinutes =  "00"
}

struct SampleTimeCounterStruct {
    var showerTimeMinutes =  "00"
}

When I update the showerTimeMinutes property in SampleTimeCounterStruct (which is a struct), the view updates as expected. However, when I update the showerTimeMinutes property in SampleTimeCounter (which is a class), the view does not update. However I have used the @Publshed property and it not updating the view as well.

…the view does not update. This is also expected (and even intended). Unlike a struct which gets copied a class does not change its reference when a property changes. You have to call objectWillChange.send() on the class instance before changing the value.

You can use @State with your custom structs. No need for the object or @Published.

Actually I want to keep all my login in ViewModel that Why I have to use @Published for struct. @malhal

In SwiftUI the View structs should be your view model. Make your login logic be a func somewhere.

As @vadian pointed out, @Published works with value type rather than reference type. Under the hood, objectWillChange will be fired whenever a property changes, to notify the listener(s).
So, if that's the case and you still want to make it work on the other reference type, try this approach. However, struct is still the right way to go so far:
Button("Update Minutes Class") {
    //Create a new instance
    viewModel.timeCounter = SampleTimeCounter(showerTimeMinutes: Int.random(in: 0...100).description)
}

